Problem Next js dynamic pages with i18n library
I have a dynamic page in Next JS and I want to use i18n library for localization, but when I enter the dynamic page language change to default 'En'. I am using getStaticProps and getStaticPaths in this page as you can see in the below. When I use useRouter and provide the locale, the locale is correct, but at the getStaticProps and getStaticPaths it has changed.
export const getStaticProps = async (context: any) => {
  const {locale, params} = context;
  rest code.... here...
  const newData = {
    ...prj,
    image: imageSrc,
  };
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale)),
      data: newData,
    },
  };
};

and this getStaticPaths:
export const getStaticPaths = async (context: any) => {
    const {locales} = context;
    const {data} = await getPosts();
    const dataIds = data.map((item: any) => item.id);
    const paths = dataIds.flatMap((item: any) => {

    return locales.map((locale: any) => {
      return {
        params: {
          id: String(item),
        },
        locale: locale,
      };
    });
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
};

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks
I have read previous issue in stack and other articles and have done most of them but I can't solve the issue

Which i18n library are you using? Or is it before you actually applied i18n library that you want to use?
